# What does “you're built to scale”mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> It's not uncommon to rent render machines for big projects instead of buying.That way,you're built to scale.

I don't know what “built” and “scale”mean in this sentence and I couldn't find any clue from dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

**[What Does 'Scale the Business' Mean?](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/scale-the-business-meaning-origin)**  Merriam-Webster Dictionary

> This newer use of **scale** means “to grow or expand [or build a business] in a
>   proportional and usually profitable way.” The term was sufficiently
>   new and specialized that it was explained in the text of an article
>   about microfinancing:

Buying an expensive piece of equipment that would be used rarely would not be profitable.  Renting it for an occasional use makes more business sense and is a more profit producing use of a growing business's capital. The business is thus **built to scale** in the sense of being scalable.

Comment: But is 'built to scale' in this example comparable to 'conforming to specification' or 'ready to upgrade'?

Comment: ready to upgrade